# On eigenfunctions of the Laplace Beltrami operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, sp.spectral-theory, manifolds, laplace-equation

How can we generate the eigenspace for the Laplace Beltrami operator on SU(2)?

Comment: For general manifolds an explicit expression sounds hopeless. And also for an arbitrary metric on compact Lie groups. For compact Lie groups with a bi-invariant metric, we are now in a quite special case so it might be known (e.g., for $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is then just a round 3-sphere).

Comment: There isn't even an explicit expression for the eigenvalues, even for compact surfaces. I don't think there is an explicit expression for the eigenvalues of surfaces of revolution.

Comment: Unless it's the sphere or other "simple" manifold, like the comments above say, there are no explicit expressions.

Comment: Where can I get full information on the sphere for SU(2) or possibly the proof?

Comment: You don't even get explicit expressions for convex polygonal planar domains. It's a theorem of McCartin that the only such domains with Laplace eigenfunctions that are finite sums of trigonometric polynomials (up to similarity) are rectangles and the following triangles: equilateral, hemiequilateral, and isosceles right. [MR2480444]

Comment: @Lateef: This revised version of your question has already been answered by Robert Bryant below: *"the $k$-th eigenspace consists of the restrictions to $S^3$ of the harmonic polynomials homogenous of degree $k$ on $\mathbb R ^4$"*. No need to reopen your question, in my opinion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, with the scale for the biïnvariant metric so that it becomes isometric to the unit $3$-sphere $S^3$ in Euclidean $4$-space, it is well-known what the eigenvalues of the Laplace-Beltrami operator are and, indeed, what the eigenfunctions are as well.  The eigenvalues are $\lambda_k = k(k{+}2)$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$, and the $k$-th eigenspace consists of the restrictions to $S^3$ of the harmonic polynomials homogenous of degree $k$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$. Hence, the multiplicity of $\lambda_k$ is $(k{+}1)^2$.  For example, see:

- the classic reference: Berger, M., Gauduchon, P., Mazet, E.: *Le spectre d'une variété riemannienne*, Springer Lecture Notes No.194, 1971.
- these lecture notes from MIT (theorem 2.9): [https://math.mit.edu/~dav/spheres.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Edav/spheres.pdf)

More generally, for the biïnvariant metric on a compact, simply-connected simple Lie group $G$ corresponding to the (negative of the) Cartan-Killing form on the Lie algebra, the computation of the eigenvalues of its Laplace-Beltrami operator and their multiplicities can be reduced to a combinatorial problem by means of the Peter-Weyl Theorem, Cartan's classification of the irreducible representations of $G$, the Casamir operator, and various representation-theoretic formulas such as Weyl's character formula, Steinberg's formula, and formulae of Kostant.  It is not a trivial combinatorial problem, though.  I would suggest getting a reference such as A. Knapp's *Lie Groups: Beyond an Introduction* and then searching the internet for phrases such as *the spectrum of compact simple groups* to get started.

In principle, one could work out the spectrum for any left-invariant metric on a compact Lie group, but the combinatorial problems that one runs into in carrying this out explicitly can be thorny for all but the simplest cases.

**Addendum:** Because of [IGT's question/comment below from June 24, 2022](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415485/on-eigenfunctions-of-the-laplace-beltrami-operator#comment1093465_415595), I decided to include the example of a left-invariant metric on $\mathrm{SU}(2)\simeq S^3$ in the first few cases to illustrate what's going on.  If we let $g_0$ be the biïnvariant metric on $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ with sectional curvature $1$, and let $g$ be any other left-invariant metric on $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, then there are left-invariant $1$-forms $\omega_i$ and positive constants $c_i$ such that $g_0 = {\omega_1}^2+{\omega_2}^2+{\omega_3}^2$ while $g = {\omega_1}^2/c_1+{\omega_2}^2/c_2+{\omega_3}^2/c_3$.  If $X_i$ are the dual left-invariant vector fields, then the Laplacian with respect to the metric $g$ is easily seen to be the second-order operator $\Delta = -c_1\,{X_1}^2 -c_2\, {X_2}^2 -c_3\, {X_3}^2$.  Since differentiation with respect to $X_i$ (whose flow is an isometric rotation of the sphere) clearly preserves the $(k{+}1)^2$ dimensional subspace $H_k$ that consists of restrictions to $S^3$ of the harmonic polynomials homogeneous of degree $k$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$, it follows that $\Delta$ preserves this space as well, i.e., $\Delta(H_k)=H_k$ for $k\ge1$.

On $H_1$, $\Delta$ has a single eigenvalue: $c_1 + c_2 + c_3$, of multiplicity $4$.

on $H_2$, $\Delta$ has three eigenvalues:
$4(c_i + c_j)$  ($i\not=j$), each of multiplicity $3$.

on $H_3$, $\Delta$ has two eigenvalues: $5(c_1+c_2+c_3)\pm 4\delta$, where
$$
\delta = \sqrt{{c_1}^{2}+{c_2}^{2}+{c_3}^{2}-c_1c_2-c_2c_3-c_3c_1},
$$
and each eigenvalue has multiplicity $8$.  (Note that $\delta=0$ if and only if $c_1=c_2=c_3$.)

Finally, on $H_4$, $\Delta$ has five eigenvalues:
Three of them are $4(c_1+c_2+c_3)+12\,c_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, and
the other two are $8(c_1+c_2+c_3\pm\delta)$.
Each of these $5$ eigenvalues has multiplicity $5$.

As one can see, the eigenvalues of $g$ need not all be integer multiples of a single value, or even all rational if the $c_i$ are rational.  Also, note that if one of the $c_i$ is much larger than the other two (for example, when $c_1 > 3(c_2{+}c_3)$), the eigenfunction belonging to the lowest eigenvalue of $\Delta$ may not be the restriction of a linear function on $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $S^3$.

Comment: It seems that for a compact group $ G $ the eigenvalues $ \lambda_k $ are always integers (or at least are all integer multiplies of the same number). Is it true in general for the Laplacian on $ G/H $, where $ G $ is a compact Lie group and $ H$ is a closed subgroup, that the eigenvalues $ \lambda_k $ are all integers  (or at least are all integer multiplies of the same number)?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  This is not true for $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ endowed with a generic left-invariant metric.  It is true for a biïnvariant metric, but that's a very special case.